# Including fa icons within php tag?

Tags: php, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to include font-awesome icons into php tags, but I'm new to php and I'm not sure how to do this properly.

I have,

```
<?php echo $this->orderByList['orderby']; ?><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i>
```

And I want to have the iclass within the php tag, is this possible? If yes please could someone be kind enough to show me an example.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to put this code in a PHP file and link the font-awesome css file in the header of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output the HTML as a concatenated string, inside your PHP.

```
<?php echo $this->orderByList['orderby'] . '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i>'; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works although I'm having a little problem where the output from 'orderby' is a link, but the bootstrap icon isn't part of the link. However I think that will need to be another question. Thanks again for the help, much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways.. a few examples:

```
echo sprintf('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down %s"></i>', $this->orderByList['orderby'];

echo '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down '.$this->orderByList['orderby'].'"></i>';
```